# Clicking a button to change the HTML code inside a div

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to be able to click a button, empty the HTML code inside that div, replace it with new HTML code to be displayed.

This is my fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/3HauW/179/

The box on the right has a button, what it shows originally is what I want to replace with new html code, which is :

```
var newHtml = '<div class= .... new html code>'
```

After hitting the button, why doesnt it change to the new HTML code and display it? It is blank at the moment.

Comment: I think your HTML may be badly formed.

Comment: Check css applied to new html element, you have `left: 1102px;`... BTW, you don't need to call empty()

Comment: You have 2 extra closing div in newHtml

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The HTML you are replacing it with has `top` and `left` styling that moves it outside the box it is inside, making it hidden. Remove those attributes and it should show.

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3HauW/181/)

Comment: thanks, why is the inner box so small, can i replace the whole box with the new html?

Comment: @JennyC The inner box is the size you set using `height` and `width`. To change the height and width of the box, change the `height` and `width` attributes...